# How do I get authorized access to GCP project via python code on local machine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

I want to have authorized access to my GCP project in order to deploy ML model to Cloud ML Engine.

I have created a project in GCP. Created service account. Downloaded JSON key file and pointed environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the JSON file. Also initialized the project using Cloud Shell.

```
 import os
 PROJECT = 'cloud-mle' # REPLACE WITH YOUR PROJECT ID
 REGION = 'us-central1' # Choose an available region 
 BUCKET = 'cloud-mle' # REPLACE WITH YOUR BUCKET NAME
```

```
# for bash
os.environ['PROJECT'] = PROJECT
os.environ['BUCKET'] = BUCKET
os.environ['REGION'] = REGION
os.environ['TFVERSION'] = '1.14.0'  # Tensorflow version
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'service-acc.json' # service account key file
```

```
!gcloud config set project $PROJECT
!gcloud config set compute/region $REGION
!gcloud config set account cloud-mle-test@cloud-mle.iam.gserviceaccount.com
!gcloud auth activate-service-account cloud-mle-test@cloud-mle.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=cloudmle-serv-acc.json
!gcloud config list
```

At this point I receive the warning; you do not appear to have access to the project [cloud-mle]. Please help me to understand what am I missing that is restricting my access to my GCP project

```
Updated property [core/project].
WARNING: You do not appear to have access to project [cloud-mle] or it does not exist.
Updated property [compute/region].
Updated property [core/account].
Activated service account credentials for: [cloudmle-test@cloud-mle.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
[compute]
region = us-central1
zone = us-central1-a
[core]
account = cloud-mle-test@cloud-mle.iam.gserviceaccount.com
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = cloud-mle

Your active configuration is: [default]
```

```
%%bash
PROJECT_ID=$PROJECT
AUTH_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth application-default login)
SVC_ACCOUNT=$(curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $AUTH_TOKEN" \
    https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}:getConfig \
    | python -c "import json; import sys; response = json.load(sys.stdin); \
    print(response['serviceAccount'])")

echo "Authorizing the Cloud ML Service account $SVC_ACCOUNT to access files in $BUCKET"
gsutil -m defacl ch -u $SVC_ACCOUNT:R gs://$BUCKET
gsutil -m acl ch -u $SVC_ACCOUNT:R -r gs://$BUCKET  # error message (if bucket is empty) can be ignored
gsutil -m acl ch -u $SVC_ACCOUNT:W gs://$BUCKET
```

Receive following error on executing above snippet

```
ERROR: There was a problem with web authentication.
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.application-default.login) invalid_grantMalformed auth code.
```

Comment: Edit your question: 1) What roles did you assign to the service account? 2) What is the output from `gcloud auth list`? 3) What is the output from `gcloud projects list`?

Comment: Note `gcloud auth application-default login` provides User Credentials and not credentials from your service account. What roles did you assign to your user account (the one that you logged into gcloud with when you ran that command)? I have written a number of articles on Google credentials that might help you: https://www.jhanley.com/tag/authorization/

Comment: @JohnHanley: I've assigned Project Owner role to the service account. Here's result from `gcloud auth list`                                                                      `Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       cloudmle-test@cloud-mle.iam.gserviceaccount.com        
         mnaqashbutt@gmail.com                                                                                I can also see the project id 'cloud-mle' in result of gcloud projects list command.

Comment: @JohnHanley:  My gmail id that I use to login GCP mnaqashbutt@gmail.com also has Project Owner role. Could that be a problem to have GCP user id and service account both have project owner roles?

Comment: More than one account can have Project Owner, However, only give that role when required. In your question, you show multiple commands but we do not know which command generated the error. Improve your question to show one command and the error.

Comment: @JohnHanley: All gcloud commands stated above update gcloud configurations and return correct project id and service account in result but also dispaly the warning that I do not seem to have access to the project cloud-mle.

Comment: @JohnHanley: This command '!gcloud config set project $PROJECT' returns this error 'Updated property [core/project].
WARNING: You do not appear to have access to project [cloudmle-deploy] or it does not exist.' While at the same time it does update the core property: project with correct project id

Comment: Updating the property does not mean you have access. You either have misspelled the project ID or you really do not have access.

Comment: @JohnHanley: Error is resolved when I set !gcloud set account to mnaqashbutt@gmail.com instead of service account. Not able to understand as to why it wouldn't work with service account

Comment: This article will help you: https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-setting-up-gcloud-with-service-account-credentials/

Answer (score 0):

You have to customize the tutorial data
This:

> ```
>  import os
>  PROJECT = 'cloud-mle' # REPLACE WITH YOUR PROJECT ID
>  REGION = 'us-central1' # Choose an available region 
>  BUCKET = 'cloud-mle' # REPLACE WITH YOUR BUCKET NAME
> ```
>
> ```
> # for bash
> os.environ['PROJECT'] = PROJECT
> os.environ['BUCKET'] = BUCKET
> os.environ['REGION'] = REGION
> os.environ['TFVERSION'] = '1.14.0'  # Tensorflow version
> os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'service-acc.json' # service account key file
> ```

is typical of Google Cloud Jupiter notebook example in the different training in Machine Learning.

This error line:

> WARNING: You do not appear to have access to project [cloud-mle] or it does not exist.

validate my assumption that you aren't the owner of the project and the name is an example provided in source code.

Simply replace the values:

- Use the project ID (not the name!)
- Set the region that you want
- Create the bucket, or add this line to all the `!gcloud` command: `!gsutil mb gs://${BUCKET}`.

The bucket must be unique, the project ID also. That's why in many example/qwiklab you will see the same value in the projectID and the Bucket name, but it's not mandatory.

Comment: I've been careful to provide correct values for project id and region. When I provide my GCP user id mnaqashbutt@gmail.com to !gcloud set account, it works but when I try to authenticate using service account, I receive the access error

Comment: I've provided Project Owner role to service account and allow my GCP user id mnaqashbutt@gmail.com to use that service account. Not able to figure out the root cause.

Comment: It seems there is some sort of disconnect between my GCP project and local jupyter notebook. I first set account and auth to service account from within local jupyter notebook. Then I changed set account and auth to mnaqashbutt@gmail.com (that is my GCP user id) from cloud shell....

Comment: .... but when I run !gcloud config list and !gcloud auth list commands from my local jupyter notebook, the result displays the account and auth still set to the service account. Don't understand why the changes made from cloud shell are not reflecting in results when I run the same gcloud commands using local jupyter

Comment: No library, the problem comes to Gcloud set up. Jupyter Notebook creates its own execution environment. It's also for that it is so powerful! So, if you have set all the correct values to your Notebook, try to start to authenticate your service account (`!gcloud auth activate-service-account ...`) and tell me if you still have error. If yes, something going wrong with your JSON file or the service account email.